# How to add a line to a seaborn scatterplot created by an arbitrary function

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization, seaborn, visualization

I would like to be able to create the following plot in python (taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_model)

[image]

The data is:

```py
hours = [
    0.50,
    0.75,
    1.00,
    1.25,
    1.50,
    1.75,
    1.75,
    2.00,
    2.25,
    2.50,
    2.75,
    3.00,
    3.25,
    3.50,
    4.00,
    4.25,
    4.50,
    4.75,
    5.00,
    5.50,
]

passed = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame({"hours_study": hours, "passed": passed})
```

A scatter plot is easily created with the following:

```py
sns.scatterplot(df.hours_study, df.passed)
```

Giving

[image]

But I'm not sure how I can then add lines to the plot (in this case the logistic curve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib's plot can draw a curve over any existing plot. To plot the logistic function, just plot `1 / (1 + exp(-beta0 - beta1 * x))` where beta0 and beta1 are the result of fitting a logistic function to the given data. Scikit Learn's `LogisticRegression` is a function that can fit such a function and return the parameters:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def draw_logistic_regression_curve(beta0, beta1, x, **kwargs):
    y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-beta0 - beta1 * x))
    plt.plot(x, y, '-', **kwargs)


hours = np.array([0.50, 0.75, 1.00, 1.25, 1.50, 1.75, 1.75, 2.00, 2.25, 2.50, 2.75,
                  3.00, 3.25, 3.50, 4.00, 4.25, 4.50, 4.75, 5.00, 5.50])
passed = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
df = pd.DataFrame({"hours_study": hours, "passed": passed})
sns.scatterplot(df.hours_study, df.passed)

clf = LogisticRegression().fit(hours.reshape(-1, 1), passed)
beta0 = clf.intercept_ # -3.13952411
beta1 = clf.coef_[0] # 1.14860386
x = np.linspace(min(hours) - 0.5, max(hours) + 0.5, 500)
draw_logistic_regression_curve(beta0, beta1, x, color='crimson', label="Sklearn's default estimate")
draw_logistic_regression_curve(-4.0777, 1.5046, x, color='limegreen', label="Wikipedia's estimate")
plt.legend(loc='center right')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: the coefficients returned by sklearn seem to be incorrect (referring to the wiki). But the main part of the question was about plotting, so thanks (not too sure why sklearn is returning different values - is it an intercept issue perhaps?)

Comment: No, both are different, but neither is incorrect. They are just two different ways to estimate  beta0 and beta1. The Wikipedia page has `beta0 = -4.0777; beta1 = 1.5046` which gives a not-too different curve. Sklearn's `LogisticRegression` has lots of options to estimate the coefficients, and in the answer above just the default parameters are used. Which one is the "best", depends on the application domain.